# What is the opposite of "footnote"?

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

[This](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/footnote) says the antonym of 'footnote' is 'Header'. But I want more specific and relevant word. From the same source, The meaning of footnote is given as "The note at bottom of document".

Similarly, what is the proper word for the "*note at top/head of document*". Header is more generic. It does not refer to "notes".

(A word that means something like "Header-Note"?)

Comment: There is the term *endnote*, which refers to notes placed at the end of a chapter. But I also tend to think that *footnote* has a generic quality about it that can, in context, mean any sub-note to the main text. It is certainly a word which is used metaphorically too - *he became a mere footnote to history*

Comment: In TeX, the relevant commands are \footline and \headline (the latter gives a note at the top; typically, a running head); so maybe *headline* is what you want, although its more usual meaning is not what you want.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Thanks. But yes, Headline nowadays refers to "Breaking News" kinda newspaper report headings than a simple note. Any other suggestion which fits well in the context?

Comment: "handbook", since "hand" is opposed to "foot", and "book" is opposed to "note".

Comment: The note at the top is generally called a "preface" or perhaps an "introduction", though sometimes a "key", listing terms used in the document, might appear at the head.  You really need to explain to us what concept you need to express.

Comment: This comment is literally an aside. If you put a note at the side, instead of at the top or bottom, it's called an "apostil."

Comment: Title or subtitle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most commonly known as a [*Preface*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+preface&oq=define+preface)

A preface is a small section of text that can either be at the beginning of a document or of a chapter.

It is generally a shorter text than an *Introduction*  which would normally be found at the start of a document rather than at the start of a chapter.

There are alternatives:
In scientific papers, this would be known as an [*Abstract*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&q=define+abstract).  A brief summary of the aim of the paper.
In legal documents, this is often simply called a [*Headnote*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&q=define+headnote&oq=define+headnote) which matches your mention of a *Footnote*.

Comment: Oh there is actually a word Headnote! I never realized that. Thanks. Accepting this as answer since the word 'Headnote' fits well in context to my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

An epigraph is a note at the start of a piece of writing, more often found in books than in documents, but that's the closest thing I can think of that might be an opposite of footer.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Fee, while your answer is fitting, this site strives to provide objective answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective and could be improved by adding [references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/59/77227). Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good answers.